# Mixing cleveref, vref and ref: Argument of \@firstoftwo has an extra }

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref, varioref

I am using varioref and cleveref together. This works pretty well. I had to add a hack though, which modifies the strings used by varioref (in german it should read "ab Seite X" ("starting on page X") instead of "auf Seite X" ("on page X") for chapters, sections, etc.).

The hack for this modification can be found here:
http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/7013/vref-in-den-appendix

This also works pretty well. But I noticed that I cannot use the plain old `\ref` alongside of this shiny new cleveref+varioref+hack-setup. When I use 
`\vref{}` after `\ref{}`, I trigger the following error:

```
LaTeX Warning: Reference `Foo' on page 1 undefined on input line 38.

! Argument of \@firstoftwo has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
\par 
l.39 Second Ref: \vref{Foo}
                         .
? 
! Emergency stop.
```

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage[ngerman]{varioref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

% This changes the string "auf Seite..." to "ab Seite..." for
% chapter/section/etc.-labels, which are 'far away'.
%
% Thanks for this hack to http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/7013/vref-in-den-appendix
% and http://www.schlosser.info/latex-cleveref-varioref-ab-seite/

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\curtlabtype{}
\let\@old@cref@vref\cref@vref
\renewcommand*\cref@vref[2]{%
  \ifcsdef{r@#2}% teste, ob Label `#2' definiert ist
    {\cref@gettype{#2}{\curtlabtype}}% %% FIXME, this line seems to break it! %
    {}%
  \@old@cref@vref{#1}{#2}%
}
\vref@addto\extrasngerman{%
  \renewcommand*\reftextfaraway[1]{%
    (%
    \ifboolexpr
      {
        test {\ifdefstring{\curtlabtype}{chapter}}
      }
      {ab Seite}
      {auf Seite}%
    ~\pageref{#1})}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

First Ref: \ref{Foo}. Without this, it works.
Second Ref: \vref{Foo}.

\chapter{Foo}
\label{Foo}

\end{document}
```

In the cleveref-Hack, I highlighted the line which seems to have something to do with error with a FIXME. I don't understand this error... I need the plain `\ref{}` also, because in some context I really only need the number of the chapter/section, not anything fancy, like "Chapter X" (\cref{}) or "Chapter X (on page ...)" (`\vref{}`). I am using LuaLaTeX beta-0.76.0-2014042815 (from TeX Live 2013/Arch Linux).

Thanks in advance for any hints/pointers.

Comment: The LaTeX warning message you're getting should tip you off as to what's going on: Since you don't provide a `\label{Foo}` statement anywhere in the MWE, LaTeX cannot resolve the `\ref{Foo}` statement and hence issues a warning message. Provide the directive `\label{Foo}` after `\chapter{Foo}` and your MWE compiles flawlessly. (By the way, the answer to your posting in TeXWelt already informed you that you must provide `\label` statements so that cross-references can be resolved.)

Comment: @Mico: I'm sorry for my mistake -- in the example I uplodaded I forgot the `\label{Foo}` -- it's fixed now (above). Still, the example fails with the very same error message. Did you maybe have some old *aux files around? When the labels are already in the *aux files, then it does compile, but when I do a clean compile, it fails.

Maybe I understood the posting in TeXWelt wrong (btw, it was not my posting), then the code (`\ifcsdef`) makes the sure that it also compiles when the labels are not already there. This works for all the `vref` and `cref`-commands, but not for plain old `ref`.

Comment: @mfuglos Out of curiosity: is there a reason you asked the follow-up question here and not on TeXwelt?

Comment: cgnieder: Well, just to clarify: I haven't posted anything to TeXwelt (I only found this cleveref-Hack there). Regarding TeXwelt vs. tex.stackexchange: I think TeXwelt is only german (right?) and I do have a tex.stackexchange account (which I found to be very helpful for me).

Comment: @mfuglos ok sorry. I thought you were the one who posted on TeXwelt, too.

Comment: @mfuglos - Sorry for mistakenly assuming that you had posted the earlier item to TeXwelt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that there are two kinds of »check if macro is undefined« tests in LaTeX.

As you've noticed the error appears with an undefined label *and* if `\ref` is used before `\vref`. This gives us some clues: the internal code should test if a label is defined or not, right?

```
\renewcommand*\cref@vref[2]{%
  \ifcsdef{r@#2}% <<<<<<<< test if label is defined
    {\cref@gettype{#2}{\curtlabtype}}%
    {}%
  \@old@cref@vref{#1}{#2}%
}
```

But obviously it fails after a `\ref` has been used. How can that be? Well, `\ref` also tests if a label exists. More precisely the command `\@setref` (which is called by `\ref` at some point) does it, also by testing if the macro `\r@<label>` is defined (or rather if it is not `\relax`). LaTeX's definition of `\ref` is

```
\def\ref#1{\expandafter\@setref\csname r@#1\endcsname\@firstoftwo{#1}}
```

The problem now is that `\csname r@#1\endcsname` defines a macro equal to `\relax` if it does not exist yet. But in the eyes of `\ifcsdef` a definition `\relax` is a valid one so it (mistakenly in this case) uses the true branch if `\cref@vref` is used after `\ref` has been used regardless if the label exists or not.

So we need a test that checks if a macro is undefined or equal to `\relax`. Since you're using a KOMA-Script class this is easy: it comes with

```
\scr@ifundefinedorrelax{<csname>}{<true>}{<false>}
\ifundefinedorrelax{<csname>}{<true>}{<false>}
```

With this the definition of above becomes

```
\renewcommand*\cref@vref[2]{%
  \scr@ifundefinedorrelax{r@#2}% <<<<<<<< test if label is defined
    {}%
    {\cref@gettype{#2}{\curtlabtype}}%
  \@old@cref@vref{#1}{#2}%
}
```

and the error is gone.

Also possible: doing the *same kind of* test that `\@setref` does – this does not require a KOMA-Script class or the package `scrbase`:

```
\renewcommand*\cref@vref[2]{%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname r@#2\endcsname\relax % <<<<<<<< test if label is defined
  \else
    \cref@gettype{#2}{\curtlabtype}%
  \fi
  \@old@cref@vref{#1}{#2}%
}
```

Comment: I also updated the corresponding Post on TeXwelt